# sre_constants.error error en_core_web_sm from spacy

Tags: python-3.x, spacy

I had installed Spacy and en_core_web_sm separately and I am trying to load en_core_web_sm with complete path.

```
import spacy
import en_core_web_sm
nlp = spacy.load(r'C:\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\en_core_web_sm\en_core_web_sm-2.0.0')
doc = nlp("The big grey dog ate all of the chocolate, but fortunately he wasn't sick!")
```

This leads to the following error:

sre_constants.error: bad escape \p at position 257.

Full stacktrace is as below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/43976209/PycharmProjects/NLP_Exercises/spacy_trial.py", line 3, in <module>
    nlp = spacy.load(r'C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\en_core_web_sm\en_core_web_sm-2.0.0')
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spacy\__init__.py", line 30, in load
    return util.load_model(name, **overrides)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spacy\util.py", line 166, in load_model
    return load_model_from_path(Path(name), **overrides)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spacy\util.py", line 211, in load_model_from_path
    return nlp.from_disk(model_path)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spacy\language.py", line 941, in from_disk
    util.from_disk(path, deserializers, exclude)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spacy\util.py", line 654, in from_disk
    reader(path / key)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spacy\language.py", line 928, in <lambda>
    p, exclude=["vocab"]
  File "tokenizer.pyx", line 526, in spacy.tokenizer.Tokenizer.from_disk
  File "tokenizer.pyx", line 572, in spacy.tokenizer.Tokenizer.from_bytes
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\re.py", line 233, in compile
    return _compile(pattern, flags)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\re.py", line 301, in _compile
    p = sre_compile.compile(pattern, flags)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\sre_compile.py", line 562, in compile
    p = sre_parse.parse(p, flags)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\sre_parse.py", line 856, in parse
    p = _parse_sub(source, pattern, flags & SRE_FLAG_VERBOSE, False)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\sre_parse.py", line 415, in _parse_sub
    itemsappend(_parse(source, state, verbose))
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\sre_parse.py", line 526, in _parse
    code1 = _class_escape(source, this)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\sre_parse.py", line 336, in _class_escape
    raise source.error('bad escape %s' % escape, len(escape))
sre_constants.error: bad escape \p at position 257
```

I am running **Python 3.6.1 :: Anaconda 4.4.0 (64-bit)**
with **Spacy version of 2.2.3**

These are the latest versions available on my network and I can't download any newer versions from PyPi.

Please advise.

Thanks,
Shailendra

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are trying to load a spacy v2.0 model with spacy v2.2, and they aren't compatible. You can check whether your installed models are compatible with your current version of spacy using the command `spacy validate`.

Use `spacy download en_core_web_sm` to download and install a compatible version of the model. Afterwards, the output of `spacy validate` should include a line like this with a green checkmark:

```
package   en-core-web-sm    en_core_web_sm    2.2.5   ✔
```

You shouldn't need to provide the full path to a `site-packages` directory because spacy will automatically search for models in the installed packages, so just use `spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")`.

Comment: Thanks Aab. That looks to be the likely reason for this issue. But I can't connect to PyPi directly from my network and install a compatible version due to corporate firewall.

Comment: You can install directly with pip as described in the docs here (https://spacy.io/usage/models#download-pip): `pip install https://github.com/explosion/spacy-models/releases/download/en_core_web_sm-2.2.5/en_core_web_sm-2.2.5.tar.gz` If you click on the blue "Release Details" button next to a model name in a page like https://spacy.io/models/en, it will take you to the release page with a link at the bottom.